# How add an inline chart pulled from a spreadsheet into an email?

Tags: google-apps-script

Goal: take an existing chart from a Google Spreadsheet, add inline to an email and send. I believe the GetChart class may help, but cannot figure out how.

Comment: Question: What have you tried so far, where did you get stuck? I believe that you should at least try and post your genuine try here, so we can help you.

Answer (score 5):

You can [get chart as image](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart?hl=ru#getAs%28String%29) and [embed it to message](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?hl=ru#sendEmail%28Object%29)

Simple example

```js
function sendChart(){
  var dataTable = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                .getDataRange()
                                .getDataTable(true);

  var chartImage = Charts.newPieChart()
                    .setTitle('Title')
                    .setDataTable(dataTable)
                    .build()
                    .getAs('image/jpeg'); //get chart as image

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "example@example.com",
    subject: "Chart",
    htmlBody: "Chart! <br> <img src='cid:chartImg'> ! <br> Wow",
    inlineImages: {
        chartImg: chartImage,
    }
  });
}
```

I hope it helps =)

Comment: [Image Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) are now [depreciated](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html), so unfortunately your answer no longer works.

Comment: @Simon, this doesn't actually use the Image Charts API - It uses the Apps Scripts chart service, which is not yet deprecated. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/

Comment: See [Tutorial: Creating Gmail Inbox Statistics Report](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/gmail-stats) for another example that includes multiple inline images in an email.