# .getCharts() working on personal Gmail but not on Gsuite

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get the charts from a sheet as img. This is working fine on my personal gmail account. But when i try this test function in my Gsuite account (as admin) i get 0 charts (from 4)

I read some comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999269/emailing-a-chart-from-a-google-spreadsheet-with-apps-script) that you need to share (with link). But this does not solve my issue. Anyone an idea?

**EDIT**: I added drive and sheets API to the services. But this does not solve the issue.

**ISSUE EDIT**:
For information. This is a issue from google. Turns out i was testing with just the first chart that came up (column chart). But i was trying the get the SCORECARD. This is not possible right now..

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154996585

The test script:

```
function testCharts(){
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Chart");
const charts = sheet.getCharts();

console.log(charts.length);
console.log(charts[0].getRanges()[0].getA1Notation());

}
```

Comment: Is this the same file you are accessing from both your personal and workspace account?

Comment: @iansedano no there are both different and both are on there own drive.

Comment: I am not sure i understand. Can you add the steps so that I might be able to reproduce this on my own workspace account? Maybe its the specific file that is having problems, or even if you create a new file, add charts, the function still does not work?

Comment: @iansedano This get me thinking, i created a brand new sheet in my 'personal' workspace drive (root) this works fine. But in root/sharedFolder is does not, and this is the case.. This narrows it down! I tested it in a teams drive and this works to. So only a drive folder that is shared outside the domain..

Comment: @iansedano looks like my tpye of chart is messing it up: Scorecard chart

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function testCharts() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('use id of shared spreadsheet').getSheetByName("name of sheet in shared spreadsheet");
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();

  console.log(charts.length);
  console.log(charts[0].getRanges()[0].getA1Notation());

}
```

Comment: thanks for your awnser. Unfortunately same result. On my personal account i did not even share the sheet and it is working. So it is a Gsuite related issue/configuration

Answer (score 0):

For information. This is a issue from google. Turns out i was testing with just the first chart that came up (column chart). But i was trying the get the SCORECARD. This is not possible right now..

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154996585

Comment: Ah, well at least you got to the bottom of it!